# Can I chain calls to Angular Fire?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

In my service I have a function call to firebase using angular fire:

```
filter : function(limit){
    return $firebase(ref.child('stats').limit(limit)).$asArray();
},
```

This works fine but if I try to add orderByChild:

```
filter : function(limit){
    return $firebase(ref.child('stats').limit(limit).orderByChild('host')).$asArray();
},
```

I get error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

How do I chain these calls together so I can both limit results and order by host?

Comment: I recommend separating that into a couple of smaller statements, so you can see the results of each.  Also, does it work if you only do `orderByChild('host')`, but not `limit()`?  Do you get messages complaining about `limit()` being deprecated?

Comment: Put orderByChild(...) first, before the limit() statement, as shown in the docs. Also, the commend is `limitToFirst()` or `limitToLast()` (limit() has been deprecated). Refer to [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) and save yourself some thrashing here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like two issues:

1. `.limit()` is deprecated. Check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limit.html for more details.
2. Although technically what you're doing should work (the docs say that both `.limit()` and `.orderByChild()` return a new `Query` object), I have a feeling there is an ordering issue here where `.limit()` might be returning something that doesn't have access to the new(er) methods (like `.orderByChild()`).

I'd try changing your snippet to:

```
filter: function(limit) {
    var query = ref.child('stats').orderByChild('host').limitToFirst(limit);
    return $firebase(query).$asArray();
},
```